# WHM mysql "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user"

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, phpmyadmin, whm

WHM installed on a Dedicated Server.

I might have changed something in the security config....

I can access to PHPMYADMIN provided by WHM.

I created a subdomain called pma.**my_domain_name**.com with a version of PHPMYADMIN took from their website. Lastest version. If I try to connect through that version, it says Access Denied #1045.

I changed everything in the config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']      = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']  = '%%PASSWORD%%';
```

If auth_type is set to HTTP instead of COOKIE, I can log  in. If i keep it to cookie, the error comes up.

I remember have checked a box in the WHM to force using SSH KEY when logging to ROOT in PUTTY. I really dont know much about Sysadmin and I'm kind of stuck.

I tried also to connect throught a PHP script which work. That is really weird.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=%%DATABASE_SCHEMA%%', '%%USERNAME%%', '%%PASSWORD%%');
```

Please help me.

Carl.

Comment: don't you want `[$i]` for the user/pass entries as well? If the system's iterating and starts working on (say) server #2, then it's going to get null user/pass because you've only hardcoded entries for server #1.

Comment: Hi, $i is the variable provided in config.inc.php. So that is not the issue. I tried also in an app built with Doctrine and the smae error appear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was with WHM password generator.

It generated a password with a ")" symbol, which mysql seems to have problem with it.

I Regenerated a new password without that symbol and everything come back to normal.
I can access with any user. WHM Glitch.

3 hours of headhache ... not bad considering ;)

Carl.